# Issue connecting Vista Toshiba laptop to Airport Extreme Wifi - but a Windows 7 Dell connects fine

Tags: windows-vista, toshiba-laptop, 802.11n, airport-extreme, 802.11g

I have a Toshiba L355D-S7815 laptop. I also have a Dell Latitude E6400. The Toshiba is running Windows Vista Home Edition and has all current patches applied. The Dell is running Windows 7 Professional and is also fully patched.

Now, the Dell is able to connect to the Airport just fine (I'm actually using it right now to submit this question). The Toshiba though is able to connect to the Airport but can't seem to access anything.

Now, in troubleshooting the Toshiba, I have disabled IPv6 as well as disabling autotuning on the wireless interface.

The interface is receiving an IP address just fine via DHCP, and I have compared the routing table to the Dell and they match.

I suspect it might be something to do with the Airport serving 802.11g and 802.11n both, but I can't verify that with any of the extensive research I've done.

Does anyone happen to know of any issues with Vista, Toshiba L355D-S7815's, or anything else that would be causing this?

Comment: I would like to note that I am now at a Starbucks with the Toshiba, and the wifi works fine from here.